# Cannot delete user that was subscribed to a subscription

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3

A user was subscribed to a subscription with 30day trial.
User decided to unsubscribe "Immediately" within 30day trial. Now In CP I cannot delete this user.

I check user, then delete, and confirm delete, then the success message says "Users deleted" , but the user remains there and is not deleted.

Commerce: 3.0.6

Stripe for Craft Commerce: 2.2.3

CraftCMS: 3.4.5

Issued also occurred on Commerce: 2x version.

Is there something I'm missing or not doing properly before a user can be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/1048

And some more characters for Stack Overflow's benefit.